# C code to assembler

Tags: assembly, msp430

I've been learning C for a little while and I've just started to learn assembler.

I have this question:Change the above code to turn on both LED 1 and LED 2 when both switches s1 and s2 are pressed (and turn both LEDs off otherwise)  (4 marks)

Here is the code:

```
            ; CONFIGURE PORTS FOR INPUT AND OUTPUT
            bis.b   #0x01,&P1DIR          ; set P1.0 as output
            bic.b   #0x40,&P2DIR          ; set P2.6 as input
            bis.b   #0x40,&P2REN          ; enable pullup for P2.6
            bis.b   #0x40,&P2OUT          ; enable pullup for P2.6

sw_check:   bit.b   #0x40,&P2IN           ; check if switch is pressed

            jnz     led_off               ; if so jump to led_off

            ; else
            bis.b   #0x01,&P1OUT          ; turn on LED 1
            jmp continue

led_off:    bic.b   #0x01,&P1OUT          ; turn off LED 1

continue:   jmp sw_check

            nop
```

I know how to do this question in C, but in assembler I'm  not so sure. If you look at this line:

```
sw_check:   bit.b #0x40,&P2IN             ; check if switch is pressed
```

To check if both sw1 and sw2 are pressed in C, I would just put if (P2IN & BIT6+BIT7). What is the equivalent way of writing that in assembler?

Comment: That would not work in C either.

Comment: What do you mean, why would it not work? I'm not saying that just putting that line in would answer the question, but that line will check for an input at bit6 and bit7 will it not? how would i do this in assembler?

Comment: That doesn't check if **both** are pressed, either one is enough. You might want to fix that before trying to code it in assembly.

Comment: do you mind telling me how I would check if both switches are pressed in c then? i'm a little confused

Comment: E.g. `if ((P2IN & BIT6+BIT7) == BIT6 + BIT7)`

Comment: sorry, i'm very new to programming. just to clarify, that line of code you wrote, that would check if both bit6 and bit7 are pressed at once?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Now you need to turn that into assembly.

Comment: do you have any tips of where to start because i've just started learning assembly today and i've literally got no idea how to write it

Comment: Read the instruction set reference and see which instructions might be helpful. Luckily, there aren't a whole lot to choose from :)

Comment: i know i have check #0x40 and 0x80 but how would i write? can you tell me this so i can make sense of it.

Comment: Specify instruction set!

Comment: Do you realize from the C code you need a bitwise `AND` and a comparison? Have you checked the instruction set reference which instructions do that?

Comment: i'm using an MSP430F5438A

Comment: bit.b and cmp.b

Comment: Looks like you don't understand what C expression `P2IN & BIT6+BIT7` does. Maybe start there, to fully understand why it is equal to 0xC0 iff both buttons are pressed, and what is the result when only one of them is pressed, and what is the result when none is pressed, or some other button (s3) is pressed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: no, no, i understand my mistake now, i just don't know how to translate something like this if ((P2IN & BIT6+BIT7) == BIT6 + BIT7) into assembly

Comment: The SP430 instruction set has also `ADD` (not really needed, as you can calculate the constant during compile time), `AND` and `CMP` instructions... the translation is very straightforward, like 1:1 symbol:instruction. Just the housekeeping around to load correct values into registers and store results somewhere, or branch according to them, that's not so much C, but the calculation itself is the same. You may also try to compile trivial C functions and disassemble to see how the compiler does it.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like msp430 code, but that really isnt relevant, until you get to the final implementation.  Seems to be the struggle has nothing to do with that.

in C/pseudocode if you want to test one bit you and it and then compare equality

```
if((0x40&P1IN)==0) then
if((0x40&P1IN)!=0) then
```

if you want to test for two bits then the first obvious way is

```
if(((0x40&P1IN)!=0)&&((0x80&P1IN)!=0)) then
```

(this has a race condition we are sampling P1IN at different times so this is not a good solution)

But we know that just means we want bit 0x40 and 0x80 to both be set at the same time so we want to know if we see 0xC0 exactly on those two bits
we could

```
if((P1IN&0xC0)==0xC0) then
```

And now it becomes instruction set depending and you have to be careful of timing  you dont want the race condition so you have to do a couple of steps

```
A = P1IN&0xC0;
if(A==0xC0) then
```

so translate that into the instruction set.  Other than extremely reduced for fun or educational purposes instruction sets will have an AND instruction, you might have to do a load/read/mov from the P1IN address first into a register or memory then and that to isolate the bits of interest then compare for the specific test, both on, both on, one specifically on the other specifically off, etc.

And of course "off" and "on" can be either zero or one depending, can have the switch pull the input high when pressed making it read as a one, or can have it pull the switch low when pressed making it read as a one, so pressed might be zeros, which if is the case here makes it all simpler

```
if(P1IN&0xC0)==0) then.
```

would check to see both are "pressed"

Comment: that's my question, i've only started looking at assembly today and i'm unsure how to translate something like if ((P2IN & BIT6+BIT7) == BIT6 + BIT7) into assembly. i'm looking at the instruction set and i can see what instructions i might have to use but i dont understand how to write it.

Comment: well all of those operations are there the and the add the add and the comparison and then branch on results of the comparision.